# Minimal tooling required to test a .NET Framework project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vstest

I was trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline for a .NET Framework project on a windows runner. For local development the Visual Studio bundle contains all the tooling and set up required to run build and tests on the command line with `MSBuild.exe` and `VSTest.console.exe`

When setting up the pipeline, to avoid the overhead of the massive size of Visual Studio, we found Visual Studio Build Tools which contained MSBuild.exe which let us compile our DLLs to test. There was no standalone version of `VSTest.console.exe` available, but we were able to get the executable with the [TestPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform/) package. However, we were getting the following error with it : `No suitable test runtime provider was found for any source in this run.` (The system had .NET Framework 4.7.2 Runtime installed already, which was the version required by the Project)

When installing Visual Studio completely on the runner, we were able to get VSTest.console.exe to work with the same command.

What is the minimal tooling required to run tests with VSTest.console.exe on a windows runner? or what is the correct way to run tests on CI/CD without installing Visual Studio completely?

Comment: Do you have the [Visual Studio test platform installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/visual-studio-test-platform-installer-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task in your pipeline?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Unfortunately no, its a GitHub actions Pipeline and the only actions we could find only helped [add the tools to PATH](https://github.com/darenm/Setup-VSTest).  We installed Microsoft.TestPlatform manually and then used this Action to setup the command.

Comment: We did that using `dotnet add package Microsoft.TestPlatform --version 17.4.1` . Not sure if thats the right way to manually acquire the package but it helped get the executables.

Comment: What exactly is the test framework you use? MSTest, NUnit, xUnit.net each have console runners you can use, so no need for `VSTest.console.exe`.

Comment: We're using NUnit - I see, I assume the NUnit Console Runner would work for the use case. But why wouldn't VSTest work? We had NUnit Test Adapter installed, which was working fine with the IDE & VSTest CLI if Visual Studio was installed completely.

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, we've been using simply calling the dotnet command:

```
dotnet test --restore --verbosity minimal ${{inputs.solution_name}} --logger "trx;LogFileName=test-results.trx" || true
```

Hope this helps, even though it's not strictly answering your question.

Comment: `dotnet test` wasn't working for our project since (we assume) it's a Framework project and not a Core project, converting to Core SDK Project wasn't an option for us.

Comment: @VishnuBhagyanath independent of keeping the .NET Framework target, have you considered converting the project file to SDK-style? Or was that what you meant?

Comment: @svenhuebner nope I meant the target framework change, but yes I had considered changing to an SDK style project but was not sure if this would certainly fix the tool compatibility issues as the docs for dotnet CLI mentions .NET Core SDK as the requirement.

Comment: @VishnuBhagyanath SDK-style projects can have any TFM, including .NET Framework. The TFM is largely independent from the SDK with which the project is built.