# VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.215.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

**I have one test execution release pipeline which was working fine but suddenly it is not running without any changes .Please check below error**

- Pipeline type-release Task name-VsTest - testAssemblies     Version-
  2.* . net version on agent machine -Microsoft .net SDK 7.0

2023-03-28T16:33:49.9296196Z /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=smoke"
2023-03-28T16:33:49.9296471Z /Settings:"C:\AzureAgent_work_temp\orbnqgrxffh.tmp.runsettings"
2023-03-28T16:33:49.9296711Z /Logger:"trx"
2023-03-28T16:33:49.9296912Z /TestAdapterPath:"C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a"
2023-03-28T16:33:50.5559981Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7195222Z No suitable test runtime provider was found for any source in this run.
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7196058Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.TestPlatform.AdapterUtilities.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7196755Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7197344Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7197923Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7198478Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7199045Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7199615Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\TechTalk.SpecFlow.MSTest.SpecFlowPlugin.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7200263Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll (.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7200988Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll (.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7201662Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll (.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7202306Z Skipping source: C:\AzureAgent_work\r1\a_E3D-ProductTest-Marine-SmokeTest\drop\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5, X64)
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7324053Z A total of 80 test files matched the specified pattern.
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7569197Z ##[error]No suitable test runtime provider was found for any source in this run.
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7645001Z Vstest.console.exe exited with code 1.
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7645350Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2023-03-28T16:33:50.7698773Z Test results files:
2023-03-28T16:33:50.9908878Z Completed TestExecution Model...
2023-03-28T16:33:51.0018728Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2023-03-28T16:33:51.0021574Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\AzureAgent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.215.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1
2023-03-28T16:33:51.0025759Z ##[error]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2023-03-28T16:33:51.0096225Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies

Comment: Please properly format your question, so that actual output can distinguished from your question text. (I tried, but am not sure what is still output and what is your question text.) Also, are there more relevant (error) messages above the "Vstest.console.exe exited with code 1." line?

Comment: Note the "No suitable test runtime provider was found for any source in this run" message/error . Read the Q&A and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146421/minimal-tooling-required-to-test-a-net-framework-project). It might help, YMMV.